# Task.WhenAll doesn't wait for the tasks to be done

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing code that fetches different data parts from a server, stores them in a dict so they're in the right order, and then combines them all when it has fetched all of them. But for some reason, it doesn't work. It goes into `CombineDataParts()` before it has fetched them all. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because all methods are awaited. Please help!

```
public async Task<Data> GetTableData(List<string> partNames)
{
    List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
    SortedDictionary<string, Data> dataList = new SortedDictionary<string, Data>();
    
    foreach (var name in partNames)
    {
        TaskList.Add(SaveDatainDict(name, DataList));
    }
    
    await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
    return CombineDataParts(tableDataList.Select(t => t.Value).ToList());
}


private async Task SaveDatainDict(string part, SortedDictionary<string, Data> dataList)
{
    dataList[part] = await GetDataPart(part);
}


private async Task<Data> GetDataPart(string key)
{   
    using (var response = await client.GetData(key))
    {
        return ProcessData(response.Stream);
    }   
}
```

Comment: The `SortedDictionary<K,V>` class is not thread-safe. Could you try adding `lock (dataList)` at the start of the `SaveDatainDict` method, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: That's a terrible idea.  Using `SortedDictionary` requires a lock for the `dataList[part] = (something);` operation, but you propose to also hold a lock during `await GetDataPart(part)`

Comment: Honestly I don't think it's a dictionary threading issue.  I'm guessing all the `key`s are unique though?  I'm curious if you set a breakpoint on the `return CombineDataParts` line, if you see the correct number of tasks in `TaskList` and that all have an `IsCompletedSuccessfully` of true.  Do any of them have exceptions or anything?

Comment: If it _is_ a threading issue, could you eliminate the intermediate data structure and method all together by keeping a `List<Task<Data>>` from `GetDataPart`? Then [`Task.WhenAll` will return an array of `Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___) on which you can run your `Select` statement.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeap, you are right. Just adding a `lock` the way I suggested probably won't even compile.

Comment: @CameronBielstein ah that seems to have done the trick! THNX!!

Comment: @an007 Great! I'll write it up as an answer to make the suggestion more clear and visible for future readers. Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking my comment out in to a full answer for clarity for future readers...

As @TheodorZoulais suggests, this is likely an issue with the `SortedDictionary` not being threadsafe. This means that while the tasks themselves are completing, the `SortedDictionary` is not guaranteed to reflect state consistently across threads immediately, which is causing a headache here. This can probably be fixed by locking in the right spots...but there is an easier way.

Since you're just using `SortedDictionary` to combine the results from the `Task`s, we can completely side step the problem by using `Task.WhenAll` slightly differently. `Task.WhenAll` does two really handy things:

1. Returns a single task for us to `await`
2. If the `Task`s we pass to `Task.WhenAll` have a result, it combines those results in to a single enumerable of results ([link to the relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___))

The first point is how you're using it now, which is great. But if we also use the second point, we can do away completely with the SortedDictionary.

So just a few tweaks to your code can get us to thread safety...

```cs
public async Task<Data> GetTableData(List<string> partNames)
{
    // This time around, we will keep a list of Task<Data> instead of just Task
    List<Task<Data>> taskList = new List<Task<Data>>();

    foreach (var name in partNames)
    {
        // Directly save the tasks from GetDataPart
        taskList.Add(GetDataPart(name));
    }

    // Save the results combined by Task.WhenAll
    IEnumerable<Data> dataParts = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    // Looks like CombineDataParts was expecting a list, so convert and we're done!
    return CombineDataParts(dataParts.ToList());
}

private async Task<Data> GetDataPart(string key)
{   
    using (var response = await client.GetData(key))
    {
        return ProcessData(response.Stream);
    }   
}
```

A few extra notes here:

- `SortedDictionary` was ensuring a sort on the keys, which this code does not. This implementation will return the values in the order the names were in `partNames` (citation: remarks on [`Tasks.WhenAll<TResult>(Task<TResult>[])` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0____)). If you want to enforce a specific sort in this method (as `SortedDictionary` was doing in the original code), you should consider sorting `partNames` with something like [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0)
- You could save a few lines with another LINQ statement up top instead of the foreach loop, depending on your preference: `IEnumerable<Task<Data>> taskList = partNames.Select(name => GetDataPart(name));`

Comment: wait. so the data saved the dataParts list wont be in order? I thought they would be because the tasks were added to the list in the correct order

Comment: @an007 Ah, I see. You're correct that the values are returned in the same order of the Tasks (source: remarks on [Tasks.WhenAll<TResult>(Task<TResult>[]) documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0____)).

I meant to convey that the ordering is dependent on the list being sorted before this code is called. The previous implementation using `SortedDictionary` would enforce an ordering no matter what ordering was passed in. I'll update my note to be more clear.